# Split one column into two by specific characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I use Python3 and need to split `price` column which mixed `price_value` and `price_unit` together in a dataframe, the example data looks like `20dollar/m2/month` or `1.8dollar/m2/day`, I want split them to this format by word `dollar`:

```
price_value      price_unit
20             dollar/m2/month
1.8            dollar/m2/day
```

I have tried with the following code:

**Option 1:**

```
df['price_value'] = df['price'].apply(lambda row: row.split('dollar')[0])
df['price_unit'] = df['price'].apply(lambda row: row.split('dollar')[-1])
```

**Option 2:**

```
df['price_value'], df['price_unit'] = df1["price"].str.split('dollar', 1).str
```

But I get:

```
price_value      price_unit
20                /m2/month
1.8               /m2/day
```

How can I split them correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Depending on Python version, you may use `str.split(r'(?=dollar)')` (in Python 3.7, it is possible). `str.extract(r'(.*?)(dollar.*)')` is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['20dollar/m2/month', '1.8dollar/m2/day'], columns=['price_unit'])

# split by capture group
result = df['price_unit'].str.split('(dollar.*$)', expand=True).drop(2, axis=1)

# rename columns
result.columns = ['price_value', 'price_unit']

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  price_value       price_unit
0          20  dollar/m2/month
1         1.8    dollar/m2/day
```

Comment: How could I ignore column `2` in your `result`?

Comment: `df[['price_value', 'price_unit']] = df1['price'].str.split('(dollar.*$)', expand=True).drop(2, axis=1)`, this also work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `str.extract` with a `r'(?P<price_value>.*?)(?P<price_unit>dollar.*)'` regex:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=['20dollar/m2/month', '1.8dollar/m2/day'], columns=['price'])
>>> df['price'].str.extract(r'(?P<price_value>.*?)(?P<price_unit>dollar.*)')
  price_value       price_unit
0          20  dollar/m2/month
1         1.8    dollar/m2/day
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAQvZu/1).

**Details**

- `(?P<price_value>.*?)` - Group "price_value": any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?P<price_unit>dollar.*)` - Group "price_unit": `dollar` and any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

I assume that you do not have any line breaks in the input, but if you happen to have any, prepend the pattern with the inline DOTALL modifier, `(?s)`: `r'(?s)(?P<price_value>.*?)(?P<price_unit>dollar.*)'`

To add the newly extracted columns to the existing data frame, you may also use

```
df[['price_value', 'price_unit']] = df['price'].str.extract(r'(.*?)(dollar.*)')
```

Here, named capturing groups are not necessary since you define the column names beforehand.

Comment: `df[['price_value', 'price_unit']] = df['price'].str.extract(r'(?P<price_value>.*?)(?P<price_unit>dollar.*)')`, this also seem works.